# how to put right sidebar sticky (only body part) in magento frontend page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, product, sticky, catalog

in catalog product page, left side i put product section and right side i put Add to Cart option. When we scroll from header to footer, it must show only body section (not on when we at top or bottom).

So what we need to change in /app/design/frontend/alokuteshop/default/template/catalog/view.phtml

`<div class="right-area">`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using some JavaScript. Below are some useful links.

`http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/`
`https://codepen.io/perminder-klair/pen/tdzue`

- http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/y3tdL9wd/

I used one of them in below page.
https://www.magebees.com/magento-2-import-export-products-extension.html